# Serilog - show object in details area, but not in summary message

Tags: logging, serilog, seq, seq-logging

Below is a sample trace as shown in Seq from Serilog.  I would like the SensorInput to be in the details area, but not serialized as the message.

How can I have SensorInput show only in the details area?

```
        var sensorInput = new { Latitude = 25, Longitude = 134 };
        Log.Information("Processing {@Payload}", sensorInput);
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Serilog's `ForContext()` does this:

```
    var sensorInput = new { Latitude = 25, Longitude = 134 };
    Log.ForContext("Payload", sensorInput, true).Information("Processing some data");
```